# Is there a way to convert a PySpark column into an array of structures from a string type?

Tags: python, pyspark

Currently working to update a PySpark dataframe's schema.  There is one column that is currently string type, but would like to format this to an array of structures.

Here's the code:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType, FloatType, ArrayType

# Define the schema for the struct
struct_schema = ArrayType(StructType([
    StructField('key', StringType()),
    StructField('value', StructType([
        StructField('string_value', StringType()),
        StructField('int_value', IntegerType()),
        StructField('float_value', FloatType()),
        StructField('double_value', FloatType()),
        StructField('set_timestamp_micros', IntegerType()),
    ]))]))


# Update the dataframe schema with the new schema
copy = imps.withColumn("event_params", from_json(imps["event_params"], struct_schema ))
copy.limit(100).toPandas().head()
```

Using from_json is returning None in the returned column, and I would like to know if there are any alternative solutions?  Please see below for sample value for the event_params field that I am aiming to transform into an array of structures:

```
[{'key': 'sample_key', 'value': {'int_value': 234232424242.0}},
 {'key': 'sample_key', 'value': {'int_value': 1.0}},
 {'key': 'sample_key', 'value': {'string_value': 'sample_value'}},
 {'key': 'sample_key',
  'value': {'string_value': 'sample_value'}},
 {'key': 'sample_key', 'value': {'string_value': 'sample_value'}},
 {'key': 'sample_key', 'value': {'int_value': 2342.0}},
 {'key': 'sample_key', 'value': {'string_value': 'sample_value'}},
 {'key': 'sample_key',
  'value': {'string_value': 'sample_value'}},
 {'key': 'sample_key',
  'value': {'string_value': "sample_value"}},
 {'key': 'sample_key', 'value': {'string_value': 'sample_value'}},
 {'key': 'sample_key', 'value': {'int_value': 0.0}},
 {'key': 'sample_key', 'value': {'string_value': 'sample_value'}},
 {'key': 'sample_key',
  'value': {'string_value': 'sample_value'}},
 {'key': 'sample_key',
  'value': {'string_value': 'sample_value'}},
 {'key': 'sample_key', 'value': {'int_value': 1.0}},
 {'key': 'sample_key', 'value': {'string_value': 'sample_value'}}]
```